# Why PHP does not return the correct results when calculating the average value?

Tags: php

I'm trying to resolve if all values from array are same, In fact. I tried calculate average value and compare it to value from array. When I code it, i received strange outcome from PHP. Sometimes it's right sometimes not.

I thought it's some php bug, in my local version PHP (5.6.10). So I test it on 3v4l and PHPBox, both services get same result in all PHP version or HHVM.

There is some demonstrative code, what im doing,...

```
<?php
$arr[0] = array(1.01, 1.01, 1.01);
$arr[1] = array(1.65, 1.65, 1.65);

foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    if( ( array_sum($v) / count($v) ) == max($v) ) {
        echo "OK\n";
    } else {
        echo "BAD ".( array_sum($v) / count($v) )." == ".max($v)." \n";
    }
}
```

You can run there http://3v4l.org/QOSaD What's wrong here? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: I think you have picked one of those magic floating point numbers that dont quite fit @MarkBaker is right

Comment: [how to compare floating point values](http://ideone.com/s9AT4b)

Answer (score 0):

This floating point magic, @MarkBaker give you link to the article.
You van use this dirty hack (redefine float to strings) to compare it

```
$arr[0] = array(1.01, 1.01, 1.01);
$arr[1] = array(1.65, 1.65, 1.65);

foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    if( (string) ( array_sum($v) / count($v) ) == (string) max($v) ) {
        echo "OK\n";
    } else {
        echo "BAD ".( array_sum($v) / count($v) )." == ".max($v)." \n";
    }
}
```